# Forwarding (Downloading/Uploading) Large File via Akka HTTP / Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a service that takes an HttpRequest from a client to get a file from another server via REST and then forward the file to the client as an HttpResponse.

Don't ask me why the client doesn't ask for the file him/herself because that is a long story.

I compiled a strategy to download the file to the file system and then send the file to the client. This is using extracts from other stackoveflow responses from @RamonJRomeroyVigil.

```
def downloadFile(request: HttpRequest, fileName: String): Future[IOResult] = {
  Http().singleRequest(request).flatMap { response =>
    val source = response.entity.dataBytes
    source.runWith(FileIO.toPath(filePath))
  }
}

def buildResponse(fileName: String)
  val bufferedSrc = scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName)
  val source = Source
    .fromIterator(() => bufferedSrc.getLines())
    .map(ChunkStreamPart.apply)

  HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity.Chunked(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, source))
}
```

However, I would like to do  this in one step without saving the file system and taking advantage of the streaming abilities.

I also would like to limit the amount of request the client can serve at the same time to 5.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already getting the file as a stream from the second server, you can forward it directly to the client. You only need to build your `HttpResponse` on the fly :

```scala
def downloadFile(request: HttpRequest) : Future[HttpResponse] = {
    Http().singleRequest(request).map {
      case okResponse @ HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, _, _) =>
        HttpResponse(
          entity = HttpEntity.Chunked(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`,
            okResponse
              .entity
              .dataBytes
              .map(ChunkStreamPart.apply)
          ))

      case nokResponse @ HttpResponse(_, _, _, _) =>
        nokResponse
    }
  }
```

To change the maximum number of concurrent requests allowed for the client, you would need to set `akka.http.client.host-connection-pool.max-connections` and 
`akka.http.client.host-connection-pool.max-open-requests`. More details can be found [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html).